# Python 3.9 - Improper Installation, Cannot Import SSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, installation, fedora

I am attempting to install the Azure CLI on my Fedora 35 machine using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=dnf). When installing the RHEL 9 RPM using DNF (step 2 of that guide), Python 3.9 is installed along with Azure (Azure is dependent on 3.9). The installation of both applications appears to succeed until I run `az --version`, at which point I get a module not found error from `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ssl.py`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

I have OpenSSL already installed properly on my machine at `/usr/bin/openssl`. Can I modify my Python installation to find this module?

I have already tried uninstalling and re-installing Azure and Python 3.9.

I have previously attempted to install Python 3.9 from source, but failed to do so, and did a manual uninstall by running `sudo rm -rf` on any directories relating to Python 3.9 before attempting to install Azure. None-the-less, it's entirely possible that I didn't do this properly.

I also have 2 other versions of Python (3.10.7 and 2.7.18) already installed.

I am very lost, and appreciate the help!

P.S: I expect to have similar issues with other modules once I resolve this problem. Ideally, I'd like to understand what I'm doing and how to apply this fix to similar errors. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by uninstalling `python3.9` and the Azure CLI, then using `whereis` to properly remove my broken source installation:

```
sudo dnf remove azure-cli-2.42.0-1.el9.x86_64
whereis python3.9
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python3.9*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.9*
sudo dnf install azure-cli-2.42.0-1.el9.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try building with the argument of  `--with-ssl` and make sure that openssl is downloaded.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How do I build Python if I installed it using a package manager?